# Telegram can't open or click image or link ,why would that happen?

Tags: image, hyperlink, telegram, photo

[image]

When I want to open or click received image or hyperlink in telegram, it doesn't make sense, nothing happens.
And these options can not be used either.

[image]

Why would this happen, and how to solve it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming and should be on Web Apps StackExchange but is too old to migrate